# PopUp chrome extension on particular websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am a chrome extension newbie. I am looking for a way to popUp my chrome extension on websites that contain a particular text(for instance "stack) in its URL. When i mean popUp, i mean to display my chrome extension's UI immediately when the user lands on a website that contains stack in its URL. Would this be in my background or content script and how do I go about it?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "tabs", "declarativeContent"],
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png"
          }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
}
```

I tried the below code and got nothing.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
   chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
     chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: [
        new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
           pageUrl: { urlContains: 'stack' }
         })
       ],
       actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
     }]);
   });
 });
```

Comment: The action popup cannot be shown automatically and reliably (chrome.action.openPopup can clash with other extensions), so the best method might be to use `sidePanel` API or add an element to the web page itself.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just want my chrome extension's UI to popUp on websites with a particular text in its URL. Sidepanel doesn't do that.